# Procedural Mesh - Looping Vertices Back to Start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertices

I have a simple question: I want to create a procedural mesh that loops the vertices at a specific point back to the start.

But it is **toggling** between the **source** and **destination** position very fast. I don't know where the problem is.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Here is my Code: (is just written & optimized for the X negative axis)

```
void GridHandler()
{
    for (int v = 0; v <= verts.Length - 1; v++)
    {
        if (verts[v].x < -1f)
        {
            verts[v] = new Vector3((width * segWidth), 0, defaultPos[v].z);
        }
        else if (verts[v].x > (width * segWidth + 1))
        {
            verts[v] = new Vector3(defaultPos[v].x, -10, defaultPos[v].z);
        }
        else if (verts[v].z < -1f)
        {
            verts[v] = new Vector3(defaultPos[v].x, -10, defaultPos[v].z);
        }
        else if (verts[v].z > (depth * segDepth + 1))
        {
            verts[v] = new Vector3(defaultPos[v].x, -10, defaultPos[v].z);
        }
        else
        {
            verts[v] = defaultPos[v];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Picture is not clear enough, don't understand the task. Moving that many vertices sounds like it will be slower than moving a batched group of quads around. And more difficult to program. If i was looping a lot of squares around another squar procedurally, I would just put all their vertices in an array and loop that. it would require having no shared vertices and it seems way complex and illogical. vertices are like changing the weave in the jumper and then weaving all the other weaves to fit in. sounds like a very specific debug, your question requires someone to run it all on their platform

Comment: So i go on stack, I look for vertices/mesh questions to answer from the week, and I get posts from 2011, and no time-sort button.